# How to fix android bootloop?

Tags: android

I am installing Stock rom on my Galaxy S5 G900F (Rom:G900FXXS1LV). Lat time I installed my phone turned. 
Now when I installed after rebooting the device it says Upgrading phone ad than erasing, after that phone is stuck in boot-loop.
I have tried installing rom several times and also wiped cache and data before installing but it's not working.
Any help??

Comment: If you have backup then restore your backup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try and install a custom recovery like TWRP from Download Mod, using Odin (Windows) or heimdall (Linux).

After installing the newest TWRP recovery, reboot to recovery mode using the trigger (Volume UP + Home Button + Power Button) when the device is turned off.

Once you are on TWRP recovery, you can connect the device via USB to the computer, then transfer any zip file of a ROM you would want, and after doing Factory Reset (Wipe) you can install any zip update you want.

If that doesn't help - I suggest doing full wipe from TWRP recovery and then flash a new ROM from Download Mod using Odin.